# Can I vectorise this python code?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I have written this python code to get neighbours of a label (a set of pixels sharing some common properties). The neighbours for a label are defined as the other labels that lie on the other side of the boundary (the neighbouring labels share a boundary). So, the code I wrote works but is extremely slow:

```
# segments: It is a 2-dimensional numpy array (an image really)
# where segments[x, y] = label_index. So each entry defines the
# label associated with a pixel.

# i: The label whose neighbours we want.

def get_boundaries(segments, i):
    neighbors = []
    for y in range(1, segments.shape[1]):
        for x in range(1, segments.shape[0]):
            # Check if current index has the label we want 
            if segments[x-1, y] == i:
                # Check if neighbour in the x direction has
                # a different label
                if segments[x-1, y] != segments[x, y]:
                    neighbors.append(segments[x,y])

            # Check if neighbour in the y direction has
            # a different label
            if segments[x, y-1] == i:
                if segments[x, y-1] != segments[x, y]:
                    neighbors.append(segments[x, y])

    return np.unique(np.asarray(neighbors))
```

As you can imagine, I have probably completely misused python here. I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this code to make it more pythonic.

Comment: There are certainly ways to make the code more pythonic, but doing this probably won't have much of an impact on performance if that is what you are hoping for

Comment: You could fuse your if statements together like "if segments[x-1, y] == i and segments[x-1, y] != segments[x, y]:" but you can't make it faster

Comment: For segmenting and/or labelling measurements, i suggest looking a bit at https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/index.html#measuring-objects-properties-ndimage-measurements Thats what i use for labelling pixels inside an image and stuff like that. (take a look at it, and if that does what you want, i can write an answer about it, giving some more detail)

Comment: Do you actually want only the neighbors to the right and below each matching-label pixel?  That's what your code does now...not "neighbors" generally, but only neighbor in specific directions.

Comment: @John: yes, only neighbours in the right/down directions, this will get all the connected neighbours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def get_boundaries2(segments, i):
    x, y = np.where(segments == i) # where i is
    right = x + 1
    rightMask = right < segments.shape[0] # keep in bounds
    down = y + 1
    downMask = down < segments.shape[1]
    rightNeighbors = segments[right[rightMask], y[rightMask]]
    downNeighbors = segments[x[downMask], down[downMask]]
    neighbors = np.union1d(rightNeighbors, downNeighbors)
    return neighbors
```

As you can see, there are no Python loops at all; I also tried to minimize copies (the first attempt made a copy of `segments` with a NAN border, but then I devised the "keep in bounds" check).

Note that I did not filter out `i` itself from the "neighbors" here; you can add that easily at the end if you want.  Some timings:

Input 2000x3000: original takes 13 seconds, mine takes 370 milliseconds (35x speedup).

Input 1000x300: original takes 643 ms, mine takes 17.5 ms (36x speedup).

Comment: I'm puzzled what `right[rightMask]` does. Isn't `right` of type `int`? And `rightMask` should be a boolean value?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: no, `right` is `x + 1` and `x` is the first dimension ("column") where `i` is located.  `len(x)` will equal the number of times `i` is in `segments`, and `len(right)` will also be that length.

Comment: Okay, I start to get it. So `len(right)` is `len(x)-1`? And that means `rightMask` is not boolean, either?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: no, incorrect on both counts.  Try it in your own Python REPL and see.  :)  The lengths are the same, and the masks are indeed boolean.

Comment: Wow, that is indeed fast!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your for loops with numpy's implicit looping.

I don't know enough about your code to convert it directly, but I can give an example.

Suppose you have an array of 100000 random integers, and you need to get an array of each element divided by its neighbor.

```
import random, numpy as np 
a = np.fromiter((random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(100000)), int)
```

One way to do this would be:

```
[a[i] / a[i+1] for i in range(len(a)-1)]
```

Or this, which is much faster:

```
a / np.roll(a, -1)
```

Timeit:

```
initcode = 'import random, numpy as np; a = np.fromiter((random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(100000)), int)'
timeit.timeit('[a[i] / a[i+1] for i in range(len(a)-1)]', initcode, number=100)
5.822079309000401
timeit.timeit('(a / np.roll(a, -1))', initcode, number=100)
0.1392055350006558
```

Comment: I will see if I can use this somehow. I made some edits to the code and will update the thread soon.